# Can't get clipboard printed to GUI to update on autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

So I can't seem to get it to change, it's supposed to print out whatever I have copied to my clipboard onto the gui. but I can't seem to get it to update

```
b = 0
Gui, New, +Resize -MaximizeBox, Farming
Gui, Color, EEAA99
Gui +LastFound 
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99(True)
Gui, Farming:+AlwaysOnTop +Disabled -SysMenu +Owner
while(True)
{
new1 = %clipboard%
if(b == 0)
{
    Gui, Farming:Add, Text, Vkek, Current copied: %new1%
    Gui, Farming:Show, AutoSize Center
    clips = %new1%
    b = 1
}
if(%new1% <> %clips%)
{
    b = 0
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `if(%new1% <> %clips%)` to `if(new1 <> clips)`. You can read about comparing variables in the documentation here:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions

Once that is fixed you are going to have another issue in that you will be trying to add a new text control to your gui with the same variable as an existing control (kek). Instead, you need to change the content of the text control using GuiControl command:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm